# Database Connectivity with java to any database by single configuration file

Tags: java, database

How can we configure any database with java through configuration file.
Means can i switch to any any database from java through configuration file.
This is my code to configure with mySql database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <jdbc>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase</url>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <username>java</username>
        <password>d$7hF_r!9Y</password>
</jdbc>
</config>
```

Like that i want to configure to any database like(oracle, sqlserver) with java by single configuration file. Can it be possible ? 
and how to call it in my java application

Comment: As long as the SQL is compatible there should be no problems

Comment: i just want connectivity

Comment: would you give me config file through that all database can be connected by seleting

Comment: for every database you will have to write an own config file

Comment: means for every database there should be separate file ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swing or JSP. Only add relevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible?  Within certain bounds, yes.  The bounds are that you must restrict yourself to using SQL that all of the databases that you want to use can understand.  This can be a problem, because different databases use non-standard syntax, non-standard extensions, support different sets of data types have different languages for stored procedures, triggers and so on.

The problem is that the more databases you support the smaller set of SQL that they have in common.  Soon you get to the point that you need to generate / use different SQL depending on the database.  Before then, you need to use a database abstraction layer in your code ... or an ORM like Hibernate.

---

The config is the easy bit.  You load the driver class and then call `DriverManager.getConnection` with the URL, username and password in the config file; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: what will be the procedure how can i switch to other database by configuration file

Comment: By changing the config file.  I forgot to mention that you need to **write some Java code** that will read the config file, and do the things I described.  (And what you have shown us is not code.  It is an XML config file.)

Comment: i dont have idea to do this

Comment: because i came from ASP.NET background

Comment: Well, I'm afraid, you will either need to learn Java, or employ a Java programmer.  This site is not a "write my code for free" site.